# Create event with rule in android calendar programatically

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am creating an event in android calendar which have a recurrence rule. The code is as follows:-

```
public long createEvents_Usertimelineview()
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    long calID = 11;
    long startMillis = 0; 
    long endMillis = 0;

    String startdate_arr[]= {"2015", "05", "12"};
    String starttime_arr[]={"14", "00", "00"};


    calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(startdate_arr[0]),Integer.parseInt(startdate_arr[1])-1,
            Integer.parseInt(startdate_arr[2]),Integer.parseInt(starttime_arr[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(starttime_arr[1]),Integer.parseInt(starttime_arr[2])); // start Time: 00, 01,59

    startMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();   


    String  startdate_arr1[]=  {"2015", "05", "12"};
    String  starttime_arr1[]=  {"15", "30", "00"};

    calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(startdate_arr1[0]),Integer.parseInt(startdate_arr1[1])-1,
            Integer.parseInt(startdate_arr1[2]),Integer.parseInt(starttime_arr1[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(starttime_arr1[1]),Integer.parseInt(starttime_arr1[2])); //End Time: 23, 58,00


    endMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Calendar calendar2=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(startMillis-endMillis);


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "My Grand Demo Event");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, "usertimelinedata");

    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,"FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=16;BYDAY=TU");

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM,0);

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,"");

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,"");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    Log.e("","Event generate id.. "+eventID);

    return eventID;

}
```

Now, the event is created perfectly fine. The problem is, in android calendar this event only showing for few weeks and after some weeks it does not view in calendar while according to its rrule it should show 16 times.
Start date of event is 12 May 2015 and its never end. Similarly the same issue is occurring for all the events having rrule. Only HTC desire device showing the events in a perfect manner while issue is coming in moto g and samsung device. Please help to sort out this problem...!
[image]

when I swipe the calendar this event is no more..

[image]

Comment: Can you please summarize your issue?

Comment: I have explained the issue in very detail and simple. Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Signare, Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Is there no one in this world who can solve such type of issue ??

Comment: Hey if you're confused on creating proper RRULE then you can use this website
https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/rrule-generator

Comment: this is your inbuild app calendar or google calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set event DURATION instead of DTEND.
So comment this line values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
Add this line  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "PT1H"); 
PT1H means 1 hour . It is RFC 545 formats.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to put endMillis in this line. How can I convert endMillis to pt1H format ? Please suggest me....

Comment: I don`t know how to do that . For my aplication i needed 1 hour events. You can read here about RFC 5545 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.5 .